# Cannot call a value of non-function type DateCallBack

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

The piece of code I am writing used to work charm before migrating to swift 3. But the, doomsday, I am migrating it to XCode 8 and I can't seem to resolve this bug in my code. This issue is out of my understanding. I think  I have missed the basics over here.
`DateCallBack` is a typealias I defined before declaring my class.

```
typealias DateCallBack = ((_ year: Int?, _ month: Int?) -> Void)
```

Then I have declared an instance of DateCallBack.

```
private var callBack: DateCallBack!
```

And then within an extension of the class, I have implemented two methods

```
 func cancelButtonAction() {
    self.callBack(year: nil, month: nil)
    self.animateOut { (completion) in
        if completion {
            self.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}

func doneButtonAction(_ yearIndex: Int!, monthIndex: Int!) {
    self.callBack(year: yearIndex, month: monthIndex)
    self.animateOut { (completion) in
        if completion {
            self.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

And the error I get is `Cannot call a value of non-function type DateCallBack`on both functions self.callBack that is second line of both the functions.
Please explain me what I have missed too.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you call it like this `self.callBack(yearIndex, monthIndex)` ?

Comment: Thank you mate, that was the problem I couldn't figure out.

Comment: You're welcome, I'll transform the comment into an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the function is defined as `(_ year: Int?, _ month: Int?) -> Void` so there is no parameter name when it's called (because of the `_` before each parameter).

So you call it like this:

```
self.callBack(yearIndex, monthIndex)
```

If you want the function call to look like in your code

```
self.callBack(year: yearIndex, month: monthIndex)
```

you should define the function like below:

```
(year: Int?, month: Int?) -> Void
```

Comment: beautifully explained, as I required!

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue, thank you @[bogdanf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/554203/bogdanf)

```
self.callBack(yearIndex, monthIndex)
```